# How to associate a list of character vectors with your data frame in R

Tags: r

The shape of my data is fairly simple:

```
set.seed(1337)
id <- c(1:4)
values <- runif(0, 1, n=4)
df <- data.frame(id, values) 
df
  id     values
1  1 0.57632155
2  2 0.56474213
3  3 0.07399023
4  4 0.45386562
```

What isn't simple: I have a list of character-value arrays that match up to each row, where each list item can be empty, or it can contain up to 5 separate tags, like...

```
tags <- list(
  c("A"),
  NA,
  c("A", "B", "C"),
  c("B", "C")
)
```

I will be asked various questions using the tags as classifers, for instance, "what is the average value of all rows with a B tag?" Or "how many rows contain both tag A and tag C?"

What way would you choose to store the tags so that I can do this? My real-life data file is quite large, which makes experimenting with `unlist` or other commands difficult.

Comment: You have several questions.  What is your expected output?  May be `df %>% mutate(tag = tags) %>% unnest %>% group_by(tag) %>% summarise(n = n(), Mean = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Or it coul dbe `df %>% mutate(tag = tags) %>% unnest %>% summarise(nAC = sum(tag %in% c("A", "C")), meanB = mean(values[tag == "B"], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Clients are unpredictable, as are the people within my own company who might request deliverables. I can't always anticipate what questions I will be asked. So I'm asking you, "how would you store these tags so as to be most flexible?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of options to get the expected output.  Create 'tags' as a `list` column in the dataset and `unnest` (already from the comments), and then `summarise` the number of 'A' or 'C' by getting the `sum` of logical vector.  Similarly, the `mean` of 'values' where 'tag' is 'B'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(tag = tags) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  summarise(nAC = sum(tag %in% c("A", "C")), 
            meanB = mean(values[tag == "B"], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not very hard . you just need assign your list to your df create a new columns as name tags then we do `unnest`, I have list the solutions for your listed questions .

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df$tags=list(
     c("A"),
     NA,
     c("A", "B", "C"),
     c("B", "C")
 )
Newdf=df%>%tidyr::unnest(tags)
```

---

***`Q1.`***

```
Newdf%>%group_by(tags)%>%summarise(Mean=mean(values))%>%filter(tags=='B')
   tags              Mean
  <chr>             <dbl>
1     B 0.263927925960161
```

---

***`Q2.`***

```
Newdf%>%group_by(id)%>%dplyr::summarise(Count=any(tags=='A')&any(tags=='C'))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id Count
  <int> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE
2     2    NA
3     3  TRUE
4     4 FALSE
```